# How to implement jQuery Event Listener to document in Meteor

Tags: jquery, events, meteor, listener

I'm using an API that loads a widget on to my site. When the process in the widget is finished, it fires an event to the document so I can take action and redirect users etc.

My problem is that I don't know how to capture that event. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the listener as displayed on the API docs

```
//Complete Listener
DIDjQuery(document).on('complete', function(didEvent, didEventData) {

    didEvent.eventData = didEventData;

    console.log(didEvent);
});
```

And here's a link to the docs: http://developers.direct.id/content/events

It's the "widget completion" I'm trying to use.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put that code in your template's onRendered callback, like so:

```
Template.foo.onRendered(function() {

    //Complete Listener
    DIDjQuery(document).on('complete', function(didEvent, didEventData) {

        didEvent.eventData = didEventData;

        console.log(didEvent);

    });
});
```

If you are doing template level subscriptions, or something else where you need to wait for the UI to re-render, you can wrap in a Tracker.afterFlush callback.  Since you are attaching the listener to the document rather than a specific element you probably won't need to do this

```
Template.foo.onRendered(function() {
    var template = this;

    template.subscribe("mySubscription", function() {

        Tracker.afterFlush(function() {

            //Complete Listener
            DIDjQuery(document).on('complete', function(didEvent, didEventData) {

                didEvent.eventData = didEventData;

                console.log(didEvent);
            });

        });

    });

});
```